# Изменение состояния при добавлении элемента в массив?

Tags: javascript, массивы, reactjs

такой вопрос, есть массив cls, мне нужно , чтобы при наведении на элемент списка в дочернем элементе, бг из state пушился в массив cls и этим самым менялся фон Layout, дело в том, что элементы пушатся, но бг не меняется

```
import React from 'react'
import './Layout.scss'
import NavBar from '../components/navBar/NavBar'
import Footer from '../components/footer/Footer'

class Layout extends React.Component {
state = {
    isHovered: false,
    list: [
        {name: 'Behance', id: 1, background: 'blue'},
        {name: 'Dribbble', id: 2, background: 'red'},
        {name: 'Instagram', id: 3, background: 'green'},
    ],
    cls : [
        'Layout'
    ]

}

handleHover = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        isHovered: !prevState.isHovered
    }));
}



render (){
    return (
        <div className = {this.state.cls.join('')}>
            <NavBar/>
            <Footer
                list = {this.state.list}
                hover = {this.handleHover = this.handleHover.bind(this)}
                cls = {this.state.cls}
                handleState = {this.handleState}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
}

export default Layout
```

Вот дочерний элемент

```
import React from 'react'
import classes from './Footer.module.scss'
import Typed from 'react-typed';

const Footer = props => {


return (
    <div className = {classes.Footer}>
        <div className = {classes.left}>
            <Typed
                strings={['Пока мы кому-то разрабатываем новый сайт, можете 
взглянуть на портфолио',]}
                typeSpeed={40}
            />
            <br/>

            <h4>
                презентация.pdf
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div className = {classes.center}>
            <h4>
                info@begoody.com
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div className = {classes.right}>
            <ul>
                {props.list.map((li, index) => {
                    return (
                        <li   
                            onMouseLeave= {() => 
                              props.cls.splice(li.background)}
                            onMouseEnter = {() => 
                             props.cls.push(li.background)} 
                            key = {index + 1}
                        >
                            {li.name}
                        </li>
                    )
                })}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
)
}

export default Footer
```

Answer (score 0):

Передайте из Layout компонента в дочерний элемент обработчики событий onMouseLeave, onMouseEnter и передавайте аргументом цвет.

```js
import React from 'react'
import './Layout.scss'
import NavBar from '../components/navBar/NavBar'
import Footer from '../components/footer/Footer'

class Layout extends React.Component {
  state = {
      isHovered: false,
      list: [
          {name: 'Behance', id: 1, background: 'blue'},
          {name: 'Dribbble', id: 2, background: 'red'},
          {name: 'Instagram', id: 3, background: 'green'},
      ],
      cls : [
          'Layout'
      ]

  }

  handleHover = () => {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
          isHovered: !prevState.isHovered
      }));
  }
  
  itemMouseEnterHandler = (color) => () => {
    this.setState((state) => ({
      cls: [...state.cls, color],
    });
  }
  
  itemMouseLeaveHandler = (color) => () => {
    this.setState((state) => ({
      cls: state.cls.filter((i) => i !== color),
    });
  }


  render (){
      return (
          <div className = {this.state.cls.join(' ')}>
              <NavBar/>
              <Footer
                  list = {this.state.list}
                  hover = {this.handleHover = this.handleHover.bind(this)}
                  cls = {this.state.cls}
                  handleState = {this.handleState}
                  onItemMouseEnter = { this.itemMouseEnterHandler }
                  onItemMouseLeave = { this.itemMouseLeaveHandler }
              />
          </div>
      )
  }
}

export default Layout
```

А в дочернем укажите обработчики элементу

```html
import React from 'react'
import classes from './Footer.module.scss'
import Typed from 'react-typed';

const Footer = props => {


return (
    <div className = {classes.Footer}>
        <div className = {classes.left}>
            <Typed
                strings={['Пока мы кому-то разрабатываем новый сайт, можете 
взглянуть на портфолио',]}
                typeSpeed={40}
            />
            <br/>

            <h4>
                презентация.pdf
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div className = {classes.center}>
            <h4>
                info@begoody.com
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div className = {classes.right}>
            <ul>
                {props.list.map((li, index) => {
                    return (
                        <li   
                            onMouseLeave= { props.onItemMouseEnter(li.background) }
                            onMouseEnter = { props.onItemMouseLeave(li.background) } 
                            key = {index + 1}
                        >
                            {li.name}
                        </li>
                    )
                })}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
)
}

export default Footer
```

Comment: И мой совет: поключите es-linter - проще станет жить)